# "adobe sign" for TeX?

Tags: adobe

[*Adobe sign*](https://acrobat.adobe.com/us/en/sign.html) is a service that allows users to integrate a digital signature to the PDF files. I would like to have something similar for *TeX in order to have a proofed signature for my job application.

Is there a tool, library or code snippet for that?

To avoid misconceptions: I am not looking for a password protection, PKI signature or a way to sign the document as a file.

Comment: @Sebastiano I cannot see any contribution when following that link.

Comment: Isn't what you want is to attach a drawing?

Comment: It may look like a drawing, but is instead a linked to a publik key infrastructure that maintains and checks the identity of the person who has signed the document. If you open such an pdf in Acrobat Reader / Profession you will be able to verify the signature.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [digsig](http://home.htp-tel.de/lottermose2/tex/dist/digsig.sty) package or the [eforms](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/eforms) package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{digsig}

\begin{document}
    \begin{Form}
        \digsigfield{10cm}{5cm}{Your signature}
    \end{Form}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Doesn't this require a copy of Acrobat? That may be fine for the OP. But, if it does, it would be good to make the dependency clear.

Comment: You mean to check if it's signed?